# Composed data type haskell

Tags: haskell, types

So, I have this function:

```
solve x y = do
            ...
            return (newx,y++[1])
```

where x and newx are [[Int]] and y is [Int].
And with this function, I will return a "value". Now, I would like to know how can I "process" this value in order to extract the 2 components and use them separately.

Something like this:

```
a <- solve x y
b <- a[0]
c <- a[1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as the `return` will wrap it into some monad, you can then get to the parts by deconstructing it directly inside a `do` block like this:

```
do
    (b,c) <- solve x y
```